# Div which automatically adjust height according to a page height

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a page and in that page, I have a `div` named `#bar`:

In the style tag, I'll write something like:

```
<style>
#bar {
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

I want to write CSS so that the `div` adjust its height automatically according to the page's `height`. I'll use the same `div` in different pages and it'll adjust its `height` automatically according to the page it is in. Is there any way to do that?

Let me be more specific. Suppose my code is like this:

```
<style>
#example{

    float:right;

}
#bar {
  width: 100px;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
</style>

<div id="example"><p>This is page content</p><p>This is page content</p></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Now, I'll copy and paste the paragraph something like hundred times, so the size of my page will increase. I want my `div` to automatically adjust its `height` after I copy-paste the paragraph a hundred times, so that the `div` will cover top to bottom of my page. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "according to the page height" how? A percentage? A fixed pixel difference?

Comment: according to page's content, the size of the page will increase or decrease. I would like to fix a minimum height of the div and if the page's content exeeds the height of the div, the div will automatically fit to the new size of the page.

Comment: that's the natural behavior then

Comment: @JohnWink see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Provide `height: 100%` to `.bar`.

```
.bar {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Also, a thing to note here is you should give `height: 100%` to the `html` and the `body`.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:absolute;` as follows:

```
#bar {
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   right:0px;
   bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pure CSS solution, you can use `@media` to change the div's size based on window size:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
      #bar {
         width: 90%;
         height: 90%;
         overflow: hidden;
      }
   }
```

This will allow you to set exact heights based on the window's parameters.

[Here is a JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t18jLgj6/2/).